# Конфликт BuildFlavors в дорчерних Gradle модулях

Tags: android, gradle, build

1. Есть модуль "app", в котором добавлены buildConfig строки:

```
buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
```

```
flavorDimensions "server"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "server"
            buildConfigField("String", "APP_FLAVOR", "\"PROD_TEST\"")
        }
        stage {
            dimension "server"
            buildConfigField("String", "APP_FLAVOR", "\"STAGE_TEST\"")
        }
    }
```

2. Есть модуль "streamview"
   в котором мне тоже необходимо менять buildConfig строки в зависимости уже от flavor-a самого streamview:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        htd {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField("String", "STREAM_FLAVOR", "\"HTD\"")
        }
        newUk {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField("String", "STREAM_FLAVOR", "\"NEW_UK\"")
        }
    }
```

1. Так вот, как только я добавляю flavor-ы в "streamview", он отваливается от "app" (Gradle перестает видеть подключенный модуль)
2. В модуле streamview тоже buildConfig не создается, скорее всего из-за п.1

```
implementation project(path: ':streamview')
```

На англоязычном SO увидел вот такое: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758477/android-buildtypes-vs-productflavors-error (ошибка такая же как у меня)
Но хоть убей, не пойму что там надо делать.Попробовал заменить implementation на комбинацию из prodImplementation / stageImplementation, но ничего не поменялось.

Мне по итогу нужно, чтобы через меню BuildVariants переключать можно было настройки моего модуля streamview, чтоб оно не отваливалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вложенный flavorDimensions в модуле app чем не подходит?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors